# Asp.net api dependency injection location

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I am following a tutorial on asp.net web api and mongodb [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1267/using-mongodb-nosql-database-with-aspnet-webapi-core) and on step 4 it talks about dependency injection and adding it to the start.cs in the `ConfigureServices()` method, however this doesnt seem to exist anymore. My web api templates startup.cs looks something like this...

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

So my question is where do I inject my DataAccess class to my web api project as a service? Thanks in advance.

As requested here is my api structure

[image]

under LGR.API is the auto generated folders and classes created by visual studios and starting a LGR.Datamodel is my custom class with my api stuff. Really new here... not sure if this correct at all. Feel free to critique with best practices as necessary

Comment: How did you create your Web API template?

Comment: updated with request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've created an ASP.NET application, and your tutorial is for ASP.NET Core. Recreate your project and pick the "ASP.NET Core Web Application" template.

Comment: Yep, ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core are different things (and yes, it's more confusing that it needs to be). The built-in dependency injection feature your tutorial is using doesn't exist in the older ASP.NET.

Comment: @Bean0341 This answer is correct, you're using plain ASP.NET template instead of ASP.NET Core. Follow Step 1 in the tutorial more closely.

Comment: I do not have an option for .net core projects... I have VS enterprise do I need update or download something for this?

Comment: Ah yeah, you'll need to install the .NET Core tools for Visual Studio. I forgot that it's not built-in, sorry about that! You can grab them here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows

You'll also need Visual Studio 2015, not sure which version of Enterprise you have but 2015 Community is a free download.

Comment: @Bean0341 Make sure you follow the tutorial closely as it explains what you need to install and where to get it.